# Difficulty upgrading to Spring Security 3.2 using Java Config to remove the ROLE_ prefix

Tags: spring-security, spring-java-config

I am having some difficulty in upgrading to Spring Security 3.2 using Java Config around customizing the `RoleVoter` to remove the `ROLE_` prefix.  Specifically, I have this from the original XML:

```xml
<!-- Decision Manager and Role Voter -->
<bean id="accessDecisionManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <ref local="roleVoter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
    <property name="rolePrefix">
        <value />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have tried to do create the similar configuration in my `@Configuration` object as such

```java
@Bean
public RoleVoter roleVoter() {
    RoleVoter roleVoter = new RoleVoter();
    roleVoter.setRolePrefix("");
    return roleVoter;
}

@Bean
public AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager() {
    AffirmativeBased affirmativeBased = new AffirmativeBased(Arrays.asList((AccessDecisionVoter)roleVoter()));
    affirmativeBased.setAllowIfAllAbstainDecisions(false);
    return affirmativeBased;
}

...

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
            .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
            .antMatchers("/protected/**").hasRole("my-authenticated-user")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
      .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
      .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

This is where I am now having difficulty, I end up with an exception in the log that look like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [permitAll, hasRole('ROLE_my-authenticated-user'), permitAll, authenticated, permitAll, permitAll, permitAll]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:156) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer.createFilterSecurityInterceptor(AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer.java:187) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer.configure(AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer.java:76) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.configure(ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.java:70) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer.configure(AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer.java:64) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:378) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:327) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:293) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:74) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:331) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:92) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a7068b50.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$3(<generated>) ~[spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a7068b50$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a17f24f9.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a7068b50.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

At this point, I am not sure where the `ROLE_` is coming from if the `RoleVoter` is properly configured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the _ROLE part you have to use hasAnyAuthority(..) instead of hasAnyRole(..)

From the JavaDoc

> If you do not want to have "ROLE_" automatically inserted see
>   hasAnyAuthority(String)

Comment: Yes, that did it.  That way, I don't need to have the custom access decision manager at all.  Thank you.